# Synchronize access to map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am using a method similar to following to synchronize access to a map.

```
public class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void add(String key, String value) {
        synchronized (map) {
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        synchronized (map) {
            return map.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Does this block a thread which is calling `Foo.get()` from accessing map when another thread is executing `map.put()` in `Foo.add()`?

I'm fairly new to Java and searched for a reference to what `synchronized(object) {}` does but couldn't find a proper reference. Can somebody point me to a reference which specifies the functionality?

Comment: `Collections.sychronizedMap(map)` will do.

Comment: Your code will do as well. It's perfectly fine (assuming those are the only places where the map is accessed). What you've done is what synchronizedMap does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this block a thread which is calling `Foo.get()` from accessing map when another thread is executing `map.put()` in `Foo.add()`?

It will block any thread that encounters a `synchronized(map)` block, if another thread is still within a `synchronized(map)` block. Your `map` acts like a semaphore.

If you want access to your map to be synchronized use the `Collections.synchronizedMap` method, or use the `ConcurrentHasMap` implementation.

If you a interested about locking in java have a look at Lock Objects.

In general it is best practise to use a `private final` instance of `Object` as semaphore. This avoids common errors like loosing the exclusive access lock object if you in any way return the map or if you provide a setter to the map. It is also much clearer.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to hear. Thanks Hannes